# About an order of calling overloaded functions of operator []

Tags: c++, function, overloading, operator-keyword

I was making my own bound-checking array class, but I got a problem that it is unable to call the appropriate overloaded function when using the operator [].

The first overloaded operator `[]` is for getting an actual value(=content) of the array instance: such an instruction`num1 = list1[2]` to be possible.

The second overloaded operator `[]` is for assigning the given rvalue to the `MyArrayList`.

But when running `main` function, it was unable to call the second one. the whole code is like this:

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename Data>
class MyArrayList {
    private :
        Data* data_storage; 
        int num_of_elements;
        int array_size;
        int idx_cursor;
    public :
        MyArrayList(int _size);
        void add_element(Data new_data);
        void remove_element();
        Data operator[](int idx) const;
        MyArrayList& operator[](int idx);
        void operator=(Data new_data);
        ~MyArrayList();
};

template <typename Data>
MyArrayList<Data>::MyArrayList(int _size) {
    array_size = _size;
    data_storage = new Data[array_size];
    num_of_elements = 0;
    idx_cursor = 0;
}

template <typename Data>
void MyArrayList<Data>::add_element(Data new_data) {
    if(num_of_elements > array_size) {
        std::cout << "Unable to store more." << std::endl;
        return; 
    }
    data_storage[++num_of_elements - 1] = new_data;
}

template <typename Data>
void MyArrayList<Data>::remove_element() {
    if(num_of_elements <= 0) {
        std::cout << "Unable to delete anymore" << std::endl; 
        return;
    }
    
    Data* temp = data_storage;
    delete[] data_storage;
    
    data_storage = new Data[--num_of_elements];  
    for(int i = 0; i < num_of_elements; i++)
        data_storage[i] = temp[i];
    
    delete[] temp; 
}

template <typename Data>
MyArrayList<Data>::~MyArrayList() {
    delete[] data_storage;
}

template <typename Data>
Data MyArrayList<Data>::operator[](int idx) const { //var = list1[5];
    if(idx < 0) {
        int new_idx = idx;
        while(new_idx < 0) {
        std::cout << "IndexOutofBounds! Enter new index." << std::endl;
        std::cin >> new_idx; std::cout << std::endl;
        new_idx--;
        }
        idx = new_idx;
    }
    
    return data_storage[idx];
}

template <typename Data>
 MyArrayList<Data>& MyArrayList<Data>::operator[](int idx){ // list1[2] = 5;
    idx_cursor = idx;
    return *this;

}

template <typename Data>
void MyArrayList<Data>::operator=(Data new_data){
    data_storage[idx_cursor] = new_data;        
} 

int main() {
    int num1;
    MyArrayList<int> list1(5);
    
    list1.add_element(6);
    list1.add_element(7);
    list1.add_element(8);
    list1.add_element(9);
    list1[2] = 5; //possible
    //std::cout << num1 << std::endl; //not possible. probably not calling the first overloaded operator[]()? 
    
}
```

I first tried to rewrite the second overloaded `operator[]()` with using `friend` keyword, but in the second guess, I thought it was not a good idea, and there's no way coming up with to solve the problem.

Comment: You could try simplyfing for facilitating the debugging. Did you succeed to do that with a  non-template version, e.g. simple `int`?

Comment: @ragedhumancompiler num1 was not assigned a value.

Comment: `list1` is not a `const` object.  That is why both the `add_element()` member function and the non-`const` version `operator[]()` can be called.   Roughly speaking, the only circumstances in which the `const` version of `operator[]()` will be called is if the object is `const` or if a `const` reference to it is obtained .   For example, adding `const MyArrayList<int> &ref(list1); num1 = ref[2];` to your `main()` would call the `const` version of `operator[]()`, and a subsequent `ref[2] = 5` would be a diagnosable error.

Comment: Aside from the misunderstanding of what the `const` qualifier does or does not, the shown logic of doing bounds checking, but then if it's out of bounds then a message gets printed on `cout` and a new index is read from `cin` -- this goes against the grain, somewhat, and I would not expect that. The expected behavior is what `std::vector::at` does: throw an exception.

Comment: You realize your assignment-based overload design is inherently non-thread-safe and non-reentrant, right? And by using `operator=` as part of it, you make it *impossible* to bulk-reassign your container? I'd strongly recommend reading [the rules and idioms for operator overloading](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4421719/364696); there's a reason they exist, and you're violating several of them.

Comment: @Yunnosch   I'll do that shortly.   A bit of tidy-up needed to make it clearer, I think, which is why I commented first (to give a pointer on what the OP's not understanding).

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to call it, but you have to tell compiler that you want your object as `const`:

```
std::cout << const_cast<const MyArrayList<int>&>(list1)[2] << std::endl;
```

But your approach is going to bring you some Very Angry Users. You are breaking about every reasonable expectation users may have on your class. Your assignment operator doesn't return assigned object, it allows assigning from contained type (and doesn't allow assigning actual different container) and it relies on internal state that is for some reason set via `operator[]`.

The expected implementation should be as follows:

```
const Data& MyArrayList<Data>::operator[](int idx) const 
{
    //implement actual accessing here
}

Data& MyArrayList<Data>::operator[](int idx)
{
    // looks scary, but it's valid way to avoid code duplication
    // We first cast it to const to call const version of operator, then we remove const from the result
    // It's safe because we know this isn't const, so its members also aren't const
    return const_cast<Data&>(const_cast<const MyArrayList<Data>*>(this)->operator[](idx));

    //it's not impossible to just copy implementation from const operator here, but one should avoid duplicating code
}

// copy assignment operator. Don't forget the other functions required for the Rule of Five!
MyArrayList<Data>& MyArrayList<Data>::operator=(const MyArrayList<Data>&)
{
    // implement copying from another object here
    return *this;
}
```

Comment: Actually, not knowing C++ operators&template rules, it was quite difficult for me to find out the internal running sequences of the C++ grammars. By the way, thanks for your advice..

Answer (score 0):

The basic concern here is that you're not understanding what happens when a class `MyArrayList` has overloaded `operator[]()`, and has provide both a `const` and a non-`const` version.   (The fact your class is templated doesn't change things in this case).

```
Data operator[](int idx) const;
MyArrayList& operator[](int idx);
```

**Note:**  I'm not addressing the fact that your `const` and non-`const` overloads have different return types  (for a `MyArrayList<int>`, the `const` overload of `operator[]()` returns `int` and the non-`const` overload returns `MyArrayList<int> &`).     In short - don't do that!

At the call site, given an object `list1` of type `MyArrayList<int>` and an expression `list1[2]`, both of the `operator[]()` are candidates for being called.

When both a `const` and a non-`const` overload are available, the decision on which to call is (roughly speaking) based on whether the object `list1` is `const` or not.

In your code, `list1` is not `const`.   That is the reason `main()` can call `list1.add_element(6)` (and other calls of `add_element()`).  It is also why the non-`const` overload of `operator[]()` is called.

In the expression `list1[2] = 5`, `list1[2]` is evaluated, as a complete sub-expression in its own right.   The `= 5` has no bearing on which overload of `operator[]()` is called, and certainly does not force selection of an `operator[]()` (your `const` overload that returns an `int &`).

Roughly speaking, the only circumstances in which the `const` version of `operator[]()` will be called is if the object is `const` or if the object is accessed via a `const` reference.

For example, if you add the following two lines to your `main()`

```
const MyArrayList<int> &ref(list1);
ref[2];
```

then the `const` overload of `operator()[]` would be called.

Another example would be to create a function

```
void func(const MyArrayList<int> &object)
{
   object[2];
}
```

which would also call the same `const` overload.